# How to uninstall Gmail Offline Chrome app?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

Whenever I close Google Chrome, I see the following message:

> Gmail Offline has crashed. Click this balloon to restart the app.

[image]

I believe Gmail Offline to be a Chrome extension or app I installed years ago. How do I uninstall it? It's not listed in `chrome://extensions` or `chrome://apps`

---

Google Support https://support.google.com/a/answer/139154?hl=en confirms

> The Gmail Offline Chrome app is deprecated and no longer available from the Chrome Web Store. Gmail now supports offline use.

How do I uninstall the app?

Comment: Could it be that you have it installed in another computer that you keep synchronized with your current user? If that is the case you could probably have to uninstall it from that machine. Just a thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Took me a while to find it too, all of Google search hits have threads locked before anyone answers the question, however...

Gmail Offline can be removed on the Apps page in Chrome: chrome://apps/

Comment: Thank you! Finally uninstalled Gmail Offline after years of seeing that error message

Comment: Marry me! Please!

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome://extensions` and check or search for the Google offline setting withing the Gmail interface online.